# Git: merge to master, then push back to all branches

Tags: git, github, merge, branch

I was hoping someone could explain a better way of doing this.

Let's say I have "master" and then two branches off of master - A and B.

Typically, when I'm done with branch A, I merge master into A, resolve any conflicts and then merge up to master.

I then checkout branch B and do the same...master into B and then back up to master.

However, after doing the merge with B, branch A is no longer current with master, which is what I want at this point. I usually just merge master down to A as that would be my branch and B is a co-workers.

This has been fine, but as we add employees and trying to sync all the branches gets annoying.

I know I could prune the branches but then the users working on the separate branches would have to branch off every time. I would like to just be able to "sync" all the branches once everything has been merged into master so the users can pick up in the morning on their same branch without skipping a beat.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Generally the individual developers should decide when they want to pull from master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, lets visualize.
That is your history before you do any merging:

```
      O       A
     /
O - O - O     master
     \
      O - O   B
```

Then, you merge `master` into `A` and merge that back into `master`:

```
      O - O  A, master
     /   / 
O - O - O  
     \
      O - O  B
```

Then, you do the same with `B`. Merge `master` into `B`:

```
      O - O      A, master
     /   / \
O - O - O   \
     \       \
      O - O - O  B
```

And then merge it back into `master`:

```
      O - O      A
     /   / \
O - O - O   \
     \       \
      O - O - O  B, master
```

As you can see, doing that creates quite a mess. However, to get `A` into sync with `master` here, just merge it. It will be a fast-forward and look like that afterwards:

```
      O - O
     /   / \
O - O - O   \
     \       \
      O - O - O  A, B, master
```

OR

The better way to do what you want:
Just merge everything into master directly. You dont need to merge `master` into another branch if you just merge it back again. Even with merge conflicts, as you can't push a merge conflict, nobody will notice that you are working in branch master until you finished doing that and pushed it. Merging into master directly will produce the following result (which is the same as yours, but `A` and `B` are pointing somewhere else):

```
        O           A
      /   \
O - O - O - O - O   master
     \        /
      O  -  O       B
```

However, that leaves you not having `A` and `B` merged. They still point at an old commit. So, fast-forward merge them into master. That will make your history look like that:

```
        O
      /   \
O - O - O - O - O   A, B, master
     \        /
      O  -  O
```

When you now commit something in `A` and `B` again, they will differ and make the history look like that:

```
        O         O    A
      /   \      /
O - O - O - O - O      master
     \        /  \
      O  -  O     O    B
```

And that is exactly what you wanted right?

Comment: Geez, well this is helpful, but even if it wasn't, points for typing all this out.